# parameters in method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

Is possible to pass parametres using method reference?
For example, I have to create a `TreeMap` but using `reverseOrder()`.
Does something like `TreeMap::new(reverseOrder())` exist?

Comment: A method reference is a _reference to an existing method_.  If there is no existing method that does exactly what you want, either write such a method (and then capture a reference to it), or use a lambda whose body does what you want.

Comment: Also [External argument to method reference in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697939/external-argument-to-method-reference-in-java-8) and probably [a lot more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parameters+%22method+reference%22)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't do it with a method reference.

You can use lambda expressions instead:

```
() -> new TreeMap<TheRelevantType>(reverseOrder())
```

or

```
() -> new TreeMap<>(reverseOrder())
```

if you are using this expression in a context where the compiler can infer the element type of the `TreeMap`.

Comment: Raw types, really?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Good point, but without knowing the context, I didn't know which element type to use.

Comment: @Eran there isn't a context, it was a generic situation

Answer (score 6):

You need a lambda expression for that... you are probably thinking about a `Supplier`:

```
() -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

Comment: Thank you, I imagined that it couldn't be done

Answer (score 2):

You can't have method references with arguments in Java. You must use a lambda expression instead:

```
Supplier<Map<String, String>> factory = () ->
        new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

But if, for whatever reason, you want/need to use a method reference anyways, here's a way to do it with a helper method:

```
public static <T, U> Supplier<T> withArg(
        Function<? super U, ? extends T> methodRef,
        U arg) {
    return () -> methodRef.apply(arg);
}

Supplier<Map<String, String>> factory = withArg(
        TreeMap::new, 
        Comparator.<String>reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by method references themselves (today), but there are many cases where method references can be used with parameters using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) APIs.  Take the following example:

```
Map<String, TreeSet<String>> jdkMap = new HashMap<>();
jdkMap.put("one", new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
jdkMap.computeIfAbsent("two", key -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()));

MutableMap<String, TreeSet<String>> ecMap =
        Maps.mutable.with("one", new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
ecMap.getIfAbsentPutWith("two", TreeSet::new, Comparator.<String>reverseOrder());

Assert.assertEquals(jdkMap, ecMap);
```

Here I compare using the JDK's `Map.computeIfAbsent()` method which takes a `Function` and is passed the key as a parameter, and Eclipse Collections' `MutableMap.getIfAbsentPutWith()` method which also takes a `Function` and is passed an additional parameter.  In the JDK example, I have to use a lambda.  In the EC example I am able to use the `TreeSet::new` constructor reference  and specify `Comparator.<String>reverseOrder()` as the parameter I want passed to it.

There are many `*With` methods available in Eclipse Collections (e.g. `selectWith`, `rejectWith`, `collectWith`, `detectWith`, `anySatisfyWith` etc.). These methods increase the total number of places that can be used with method references in Java 8.

You will find examples of method references used with parameters in the Eclipse Collections Katas.

[Company Kata -> Exercise 2 Test](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections-kata/blob/solutions/company-kata/src/test/java/org/eclipse/collections/companykata/Exercise2Test.java)
[Pet Kata -> Exercise 2 Test](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections-kata/blob/solutions/pet-kata/src/test/java/org/eclipse/collections/petkata/Exercise2Test.java)

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.